# JQuery UI accordion Header not rendering properly

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I am using Jquery UI accordion widget. I used H4 as my header markup. But when its rendering, the down arrow in the header is rendering on top of the title text.

Take a look:

[image]

Please help me with this.

My mark up is like this:

```
<div class="sections">
  <h4>Title1</h4>
  <div class="section">
    <!-- stuff -->
  </div>
  .
  .
  .
</div>
```

and coffeescript to activate it:

```
$( ".sections" ).accordion({ header: "h4",collapsible: true })
```

Comment: You've probably added some extra styling to headers or ul/li tags in your CSS that conflict with the jquery stuff. User a CSS inspector such as Firebug or the Chrome Developer Tools to peak at your page and turn CSS rules on and off till you find the culprit.

Comment: No I havent added any styling.. and I inspected the code and tried turning stuff on and off.. doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines at the last of the CSS file.

```
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-icons {
    padding-left: 35px !important;
}
```